# Displaying MySQL table in CSS

Tags: php, mysql, css

I just started working with PHP and have managed to run a simple CRUD application. But displaying it seems a bit dull and looks quite ugly, so I was wondering if anyone could explain how I can select my data from a database table and make it look like [this one](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp) on the W3School website?

I like the way the colours alternate and would be nice to reproduce it when my data is read and displayed on a table.

Comment: Are you already able to get the data into a table and just want to style it?

Comment: You have to do that manually by styling the <table>, <tr>, <th> and <td> elements with CSS. Open in IE9, press F12, Select the element and inspect the CSS styling there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not based on php but on html. PHP is server-side.

Wait, I think I did get you

```
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $i++;
    if ($i % 2)
    {
        echo "<tr class='yellow'><td>".$row['id']."</td></tr>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<tr class='green'><td>".$row['id']."</td></tr>";
    }
}
```

in CSS it will look like

```
.yellow{background-color:yellow;}
.green{background-color:green;}
```

Comment: You shouldn't name your CSS classes by the (current) color that you apply to them. If your designer decides to switch from yellow to red, you will have something like this: .yellow { background-color: red; }. Name them by the element type that they represent.

Comment: that's right, it's just only example (clear than .first .second) though

Comment: Thanks guys for your tips, I will try out this afternoon when I get home. Your code looks like what I've been looking for.

Comment: Thanks genesis. Your code worked like charm - I didn't even need to change or modify a single thing in there. Thanks again and god bless.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is about alternating color rows, here it goes: you define two CSS classes for the two types of rows:

```
tr.row-even {
    background-color: blue;
}

tr.row-odd {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Then you assign the row class to each row by checking the evenness of each row's index:

```
<?php
$rowCount = ...; // Depends on your code
for ($i = 0; $i < $rowCount; $i++) {
    $rowClass = ($i % 2 == 0) ? 'row-even' : 'row-odd';
    echo '<tr class="' . $rowClass . '">';
    // ...
    echo '</tr>';
}
?>
```